# I am not able to start dnsmasq on boot

Tags: dnsmasq

These are the outputs I get when I type:

```
 systemctl status dnsmasq

 ● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-14 08:49:31 UTC; 54min ago
Process: 590 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=2)
Process: 569 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 14 08:49:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Dec 14 08:49:30 raspberrypi dnsmasq[569]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi dnsmasq[590]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.0.20.1: Cannot assign requested address
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It works fine when I start the service manually.

I have set a static ip like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf


interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.0.20.1/24
static routers=10.0.20.0
```

Comment: The log files should give you more information as to what may be going wrong.

Comment: The log clearly says: you don't have ip 10.0.20.1 on your interfaces.

Comment: It was a typo there.I had corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue

I removed giving ip like this

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf


interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.0.20.1/24
static routers=10.0.20.0
```

And I gave ip to interfaces like this.

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces


 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

 # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
 # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

 # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
 source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

 auto wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet static
 address 10.0.20.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dec 14 08:49:31 raspberrypi dnsmasq[590]: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.0.20.1: Cannot assign requested address
```

This line indicates that your machine does not have the address `10.0.20.1` on your system when dnsmasq starts up. You need to reconfigure the systemd unit to start after this address has been added. This can be done by using systemd drop-ins. Create the directory `/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d` and the add the following to a file with a `.conf` extension in that directory:

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target
```

This assumes that your network is being brought online in a usual manner, and that it falls under the `network-online.target` unit. If it does not then this will not work and you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: I tried but it's not working still the result is same.I am using it in raspberry pi with raspbian stretch lite. "Afer" had "network.target" in /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service .I have edited it there and not as you said in the /etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d .Hope that too is fine.